# Do you need a subfloor over insulated concrete?

Tags: flooring, subfloor, moisture

I'm having a house built, and I was discussing the floor in the basement with the builder. I thought I was going to use LVP over a subfloor, but the builder says they no longer put subfloors over concrete because the concrete is insulated at the bottom and sides, and protected by poly under the insulation.

The builder also does not like LVP over concrete because of the amount of self-leveling required, leading to additional cost.

Do I need a subfloor?

My concerns are moisture and the feel of the floor. I'm not worried about the headspace, and I won't be considering carpet as I have allergies.

Other questions on the site are about old houses, where they would not have insulation and barrier under the concrete.

Comment: What do the instructions of the LVP you are planning to install say? If the manufacturer requires some sort of underlayment, then you'd better have that installed or they'll void your warranty. Also, your contractor may not want to do the self-leveler, but he shouldn't care if he's billing you for the labor (it would be a contract change for extra money if it wasn't specified up front.)

Answer (score 3):

Unless the concrete is poured poorly and full of lumps there is no reason why LVP cannot be over a concrete floor.

You can use a thin [underlayment pad](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DG68K3H) that will provide some extra insulation and a bit of noise abatement, as well as an additional vapor barrier.

Comment: We had a house built 3 years ago and put LVP over concrete in the basement. We've had no problems.

Comment: LVP is put directly over slab floors all over the southern US on the main floor (no basement).  Basements have become rather rare.

Comment: They may be rare in the Southern US, @TigerGuy, but they're still quite common elsewhere.